# Android Spinner's onItemSelected executed twice when going back to Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-spinner

I created a spinner for my Fragment that populates it with data retrieved from an HTTP callout. When the Fragment is first created, I populate the spinner with its selection choices, set its setOnItemSelectedListener and set its initial selection in onCreateView().

```
    stateSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {


            if (spinnerPosition != position)
            {
                spinnerPosition = position;
                TextView stateSelected = (TextView) view;
                String stateSelectedStr = stateSelected.getText().toString();


                LinearLayout ballotsDisplay = (LinearLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.ballotsDisplay);
                ballotsDisplay.removeAllViews();

                Map<String, String> calloutParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
                calloutParams.put("state", stateSelectedStr);

                // Create and execute AsyncTask to retrieve ballots
                new RetrieveBallots().execute(calloutParams);
            }
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            return;
        }
    });

    // Set default selection for spinner
    int defaultState = adapter.getPosition(userState);

    if (defaultState == -1)
    {
        defaultState = 0;
    }

    stateSpinner.setSelection(defaultState);
```

When the Fragment is created, everything works well, the spinner position is set to its default and the spinner item is selected once as shown in the log below:

```
5009-5009/com.project.test D/TEST﹕ onCreateView called
5009-5009/com.project.test D/TEST﹕ stateSpinner.setSelection
5009-5009/com.project.test D/TEST﹕ onActivityCreated called
5009-5009/com.project.test D/TEST﹕ onResume called
5009-5009/com.project.test D/TEST﹕ spinner item selected
```

The problem occurs when I navigate away from the Fragment to another fragment (I store the fragment onto backstack). When I click back to go back to my original Fragment, the spinner seems to have its item selected twice:

```
5009-5009/com.project.test D/TEST﹕ onCreateView called
5009-5009/com.project.test D/TEST﹕ stateSpinner.setSelection
5009-5009/com.project.test D/TEST﹕ onActivityCreated called
5009-5009/com.project.test D/TEST﹕ onResume called
5009-5009/com.project.test D/TEST﹕ spinner item selected
5009-5009/com.project.test D/TEST﹕ spinner item selected
```

So I have 2 questions:

1) Why does the spinner register 2 item selection occurrences when returning to it from the Back button.

2) Is there a fix to prevent 2 item selections from occurring? Right now the fragment is being populated with duplicate data since it retrieves the data twice.

** EDIT **
After changing to `stateSpinner.setSelection(defaultState, false)`, I would get a null Pointer exception at `ballotsDisplay.removeAllViews();` seems like ballotsDisplay is set to null for some reason with that change

stacktrace:

> 05-15 07:25:48.303    6153-6153/com.poliseewriters.polisee E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       java.lang.NullPointerException
>               at com.polisee.ballotmeasures.BallotMeasuresFragment$1.onItemSelected(BallotMeasuresFragment.java:287)
>               at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:882)
>               at android.widget.AdapterView.selectionChanged(AdapterView.java:865)
>               at android.widget.AdapterView.checkSelectionChanged(AdapterView.java:1017)
>               at android.widget.Spinner.layout(Spinner.java:363)
>               at android.widget.AbsSpinner.setSelectionInt(AbsSpinner.java:292)
>               at android.widget.AbsSpinner.setSelection(AbsSpinner.java:269)
>               at com.polisee.ballotmeasures.BallotMeasuresFragment.setStateSpinner(BallotMeasuresFragment.java:314)
>               at com.polisee.ballotmeasures.BallotMeasuresFragment.onCreateView(BallotMeasuresFragment.java:201)
>               at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
>               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:953)
>               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1136)
>               at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
>               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1499)
>               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:456)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

** EDIT: Updated code to prevent onItemSelected from executing twice, needed to add null check for ballotsDisplay **

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        Log.d("TEST", "bundle = " + savedInstanceState.toString());
    }

    Log.d("TEST", "onCreateView called");

    View view = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ballot_measures, container, false);

    setStateSpinner(view);

    return view;
}


private void setStateSpinner(View view) {

    try {
        states = Utilities.getAllStateNames();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", "Error retrieving names: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    Spinner stateSpinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.stateSpinner);

    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.ballotmeasures_state_spinner, states);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.ballotmeasures_state_spinner_dropdown);

    stateSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    stateSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        // Callback method to invoke when a state has been selected
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            Log.d("TEST", "spinner item selected");

                TextView stateSelected = (TextView) view;
                String stateSelectedStr = stateSelected.getText().toString();

                // Remove all currently displayed views in the layout
                LinearLayout ballotsDisplay = (LinearLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.ballotsDisplay);
                if (ballotsDisplay != null)
                {
                    ballotsDisplay.removeAllViews();
                }

                Map<String, String> calloutParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
                calloutParams.put("state", stateSelectedStr);

                // AsyncTask to execute data retrieval 
                new RetrieveBallots().execute(calloutParams);
            }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            return;
        }
    });

    // Set default selection for spinner
    int defaultState = adapter.getPosition(userState);

    if (defaultState == -1)
    {
        defaultState = 0;
    }

    Log.d("TEST", "stateSpinner.setSelection");
    stateSpinner.setSelection(defaultState, false);
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `stateSpinner.setSelection(defaultState, false);` in place of `stateSpinner.setSelection(defaultState);`

Comment: I did what you said but now i get a nullpointerexception thrown at: 

LinearLayout ballotsDisplay = (LinearLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.ballotsDisplay);
ballotsDisplay.removeAllViews();

Any idea why this is happening now after using setSelection(...,false)?

Comment: Please check if ballotsDisplay is getting inflated properly. Seems like its null.

Comment: It does. If I switch it back to stateSpinner.setSelection(default), I don't receive that null pointer exception. Everything works fine, except for the double item selection when i hit back. I inflate the entire layout (ballotsDisplay is in it) before I set the spinner. Only when i change it to setSelection(default, false) does this exception occur

Comment: Can you please post your stacktrace.

Comment: check the top post forstack trace

Comment: what is the key difference between setSelection(int position) vs. setSelection(int position, boolean animate)? Looked through the Spinner documentation and the animate parameter isn't really explained.

Comment: If you use the later one with animated parameter onItemSelected will not be called when you do setSelection. If you don't use the animated param setSelection will immediately call onItemSelected.

Comment: Ah okay. Do you know why the ballotsDispaly is null during the creation of the fragment if I use setSelection(int, boolean), but is NOT null if I use setSelection(int)? I can't seem to figure this part out either.

Comment: Thanks for you help in this Manish. I posted the code for the class. The part I am confused about is why ballotsDisplay would be null (I added a null check for it) when i use setSelection(int, boolean). However, it is not null when I use setSelection(int). This situation only occurs during the initial creation of the fragment.

Answer (score 9):

The problem is the `onItemSelected()` callback gets called twice by Android Framework (maybe by design), the first time the `view` parameter is `null`, and the second time it is instantiated.

You cannot prevent 2 item selections from occurring, but you can check if the `view` variable is null, if not, do the rest things.

Comment: For some reason when using a `Spinner` with an `OnItemSelectedListener` in Kotlin you can end up with some weird crashes, because of this issue and because using an `OnItemSelectedListener` as an anonymous class (instantiation directly on the `setOnItemSelectedListener` Android Studio didn't make the `View` nullable, which caused an exception on runtime, because Kotlin expected the `View` to be non-null, which it wasn't obviously.
Thanks, you pointed me in the right direction :-)

Answer (score 1):

Add condition view!=null in ItemSelectedListener like this:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                        if(view!=null)
                        {//write your code
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                    }
                });
```