# How to stop onItemSelected from getting executed when returning from a locked screen

Tags: android, android-fragments, spinner, onitemselectedlistener

I have just one fragment attached to an activity using replace. When the device locks the screen after a few seconds and then I unlock it, the onItemSelected method assigned to some spinner gets executed, even though the fragment views (EditTexts and so) and the spinner selected item remains the same.

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    private Spinner mySpinner;   

    public static MyFragment newInstance() {
        return new MyFragment();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.some_layout, container, false);

        mySpinner = (Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.my_spinner);

        List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
        items.add("Anything");
        items.add("Anything");
        items.add("Anything");

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter  =
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        getContext(),
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                        items);

        mySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Hello World", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    }

}
```

Every time I select an item I get the toast message "Hello World" (or any other method or action assigned to the listener), but when the device locks and then I unlock, I'm still getting the message as if the method onItemSelected was called.

I've been trying to mess around with booleans and Fragment's onSaveInstanceState and onActivityCreated methods, but I haven't figured out a way to stop onItemSelected method from executing when the device returns from a locked screen.

Comment: Do you have to? It is unlikely that you will want the spinner to ultimately just issue the toast. You'd likely set some value to then subsequently be used. e.g. you might do something like `myspinnerselecteditem = my.Spnner.getSecltedItem()` in which case would it matter that it got set multiple times?

Comment: Yes, the spinner does different actions depending on the selected item, but it doesn't matter, because my problem is that onItemSelected executes when returning from a locked screen.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `onItemSelected` is called after `Spinner` is initialised, solution is to put `mySpinner.setSelection(position, false)` before `mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener`
refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30253238/android-spinners-onitemselected-executed-twice-when-going-back-to-fragment)